# Order total in cents

Tags: grand-total, order-success-page

I need to add a tracking script to the success page and that script requires a gran total in cents, so $15.94 should be 1594

How can I get the order grand total in cents?

Answer (score 0):

We can use this:

```
$cents = $_order->getGrandTotal() * 100;
```